# Not able to retrieve data from contacts db

Tags: android, exception, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception, cts

I'm using the following code:

```
preparePeople();
final Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, mPROJECTION, null, null, null);
String s = c.getString(1);

private void preparePeople() {
    final ContentResolver mResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
    mResolver.delete(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
    final ContentValues valuse = new ContentValues();
    valuse.put(People._ID, "1");
    valuse.put(People.NAME, "name");
    Uri uri = mResolver.insert(People.CONTENT_URI, valuse);
}
```

But while executing the above code I'm getting the exception as below:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
```

It's due to **c.getString(1)** statement according to logs, but I don't know why.. can anyone please help to resolve this error?

Comment: change `String s = c.getString(1);` to `String s = c.getString(0);`

Comment: @MD, same problem with getString(0) also, it prints: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Answer (score 4):

First, a `Cursor` is positioned before the first row of results when you first get it. Call `moveToFirst()` or `moveToPosition()` or something to move the `Cursor` to the row that you want.

Second, columns in a `Cursor` are numbered starting from 0, as are most things in computer programming. Unless `mPROJECTION` has 2+ entries, and you really want the one with index `1`, you probably want to call `getString(0)`, as MD points out in the comment.

Third, bear in mind that [there are cases where you might not get any results back](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/10/12/runtime-permissions-action-pick-contacts.html), so you might want to check how many rows you got back from your `query()` before continuing.

Comment: after calling moveToFirst() also the problem persists as I try to get the value by getString(0), my mPROJECTION has 2 entries and now the log printed is: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: @KayPee: You are not getting any rows back for your query, apparently.

Comment: yes @CommonsWare, and I also referred https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/10/12/runtime-permissions-action-pick-contacts.html but it seems there is no permission issue in my case.

Comment: @KayPee: Then your `insert()` would appear to be failing.